# How can variables be used in SQL to perform multiple functions on one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a join on two tables with SSN. In one table, the SSN has no dashes, so it starts out simple:

```
SELECT a.vSSN, b.vSSN
FROM tableA a
inner join tableB b on replace(a.vSSN, '-', '') = b.vSSN
```

But then, table b also has no leading zeroes. So I want to use the SQL substring function to remove that leading zero from vSSN in tableA:

```
SUBSTRING(a.vSSN, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.vSSN), LEN(a.vSSN))
```

If I try to use both functions at once, it gets a bit hard to read. What's the correct way to use a variable in my select statement to make it easier to follow? So something like:

```
DECLARE @var varchar(11)
SELECT a.vSSN, b.vSSN
SET @var = replace(a.vSSN, '-', '')
SET @var = SUBSTRING(@var, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @var), LEN(@var))
FROM tableA a
inner join tableB b on @var = b.vSSN
```

Comment: Please tell me you are not storing a person's social security number in plain text? And even worse making it a sloppy join across tables. This type of data should be encrypted.

Comment: You can't use variables this way in SQL.  You just have to nest your functions the way you are doing.

Comment: Is b.SSN an int? STR and REPLACE to add the 0's may work better in that case.

Comment: Security is outside the scope of this question, but the data is secure. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a.vSSN, b.vSSN
FROM tableA a inner join
     tableB b
     on replace(SUBSTRING(a.vSSN, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', a.vSSN), LEN(a.vSSN)), '-', '') = b.vSSN;
```

You should really fix your database to have proper primary keys and foreign keys between the tables.

Note:  you cannot use variables for this purpose, although you could use CTEs or subqueries to break up the computation.

Comment: Yeah, this is reading immediately after imported from an Excel spreadsheet, then encrypted to a table. Typos are possible, so I'm grabbing all of the exact matches first, then inserting the proper foreign key into those records, and then going back to find records where the SSNs match but the first and/or last names and/or other meaningful data do not. Or, where everything else matches, but the SSNs do not. I think the way you wrote it will work, since LEN(a.vSSN) will always be greater than or equal to LEN(replace(a.vSSN, '-', '')), and so the whole expression will be returned in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable, but you can nest some queries w/views, table expressions, or CTEs to split out the calcs:

```
SELECT A.ssn, B.ssn
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(ssn, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', ssn), LEN(ssn)) as ssn 
    FROM (
        SELECT REPLACE(ssn, '-', '') as ssn FROM TableA
    ) Q
) as A
JOIN TableB as B ON A.ssn = B.ssn
```

You could also use a UDF, of course.